# Input text reagent component value formatting

Tags: text, input, format, clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to format the value of an input "text" reagent component without success. I expected that, after changing the value of the ratom variable, the value of the component will be formatted at re-render.
I used cl-format to format number with space thousand separator. I works well at first load, but not after change the price value.

Is it possible to format the price value of this example after saving the new value?

```
(ns shopping.app
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]
            [cljs.pprint :refer [cl-format]]))

(defonce shoppinglist (r/atom (sorted-map
                           1 {:id 1 :name "Bread" :price 20},
                           2 {:id 2 :name "Milk" :price 12})))

(defn update-item! [fn & args]
  (apply swap! shoppinglist fn args))

(defn shopping-item [{:keys [id name price]} item]
  (let [rreadonly (r/atom true)
        rprice (r/atom price)]
      (fn [{:keys [id name price]} item]
      [:div
        [:label id]
        [:label (str " | " name)]
        [:input { :type "text"
                  :readOnly @rreadonly
                  :value (cl-format nil "~,,' :d" @rprice)
                  :on-change #(reset! rprice  (-> % .-target .-value))}]

        [:button {  :id "button-edit"
                    :hidden (not @rreadonly)
                    :on-click #(swap! rreadonly not)}
                    "Edit"]

        [:button {  :id "button-delete"
                    :hidden (not @rreadonly)
                    :on-click #(update-item! dissoc id)}
                    "Delete"]

        [:button {  :id "button-save"
                    :hidden @rreadonly
                    :on-click #(do 
                                  (update-item! assoc id (assoc {} :id id :name name :price (js/parseInt @rprice)))
                                  (swap! rreadonly not))}
                    "Save"]

        [:button {  :id "button-reset"
                    :hidden @rreadonly
                    :on-click #(do (reset! rprice price)
                                   (update-item! assoc id (assoc {} :id id :name name :price (js/parseInt @rprice)))
                                   (swap! rreadonly not))}
                    "Reset"]])))

(defn shopping-list []
  [:div.container
    (doall (for [item (vals @shoppinglist)]
      ^{:key (:id item)} [:div
        [shopping-item item]]))])

(defn init
  "Initialize components."
  []
  (let [container (.getElementById js/document "container")]
    (r/render-component 
      [shopping-list] 
      container)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because you are creating a cycle:

- `on-change` sets the value of the `rprice` atom to a string, but in this expression `(cl-format nil "~,,' :d" @rprice)` `@rprice` should be a number
- when you set `value` of the input to some formatted value, next time you type something the `on-change` will see this formatted value instead of the raw input you had before, so then the contents of `rprice` will be set to the formatted value, a string

So if you set `rstring` to the raw number or the formatted string, after a cycle it will always be the formatted string.

Unfortunately formatting the input as you type is a bit complex and you'll probably need a library. Maybe reagent-forms supports it: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-forms, if not, there are other React libraries that do.